# Logstash Error: A plugin had an unrecoverable error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

```
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_connection_string=>"jdbc:mysql://dns/db", jdbc_user=>"root", jdbc_password=><password>, jdbc_driver_library=>"/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar", jdbc_driver_class=>"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", statement=>"SELECT * FROM table;", codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON id=>"json_ff05abb6-1b36-4ebf-aba1-1f8cf47a13a5", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, id=>"93f23172918335b7f06ba3f8ee201c0b78f2c8e2-1", enable_metric=>true, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>"info", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, parameters=>{"sql_last_value"=>1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC}, last_run_metadata_path=>"/home/ubuntu/.logstash_jdbc_last_run", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>"numeric", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true>
  Error: undefined method `close_jdbc_connection' for #<Sequel::JDBC::Database:0x745d6c19>
```

logstash-5.5.0

conf file

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://dns:3306/stats"
jdbc_user => "root"
jdbc_password => "sdf"
#jdbc_validate_connection => true
jdbc_driver_library => "/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
statement => "SELECT * FROM table;"
#codec => "json"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
index => "mysqltest"
document_type => "mysqltest_type"
document_id => "%{id}"
hosts => "dns:80"
}
}
```

What is that about ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: Which version of Logstash do you have? Can you show your `jdbc` input config?

Comment: Hi @Val, I have updated the post

Comment: @Hellolad Have you solved this issue? Even am facing the same

Comment: I face the same issue with you...